# Lua (trAInsported): trying to implement Wavefront Algorithm, not working

Tags: algorithm, lua, breadth-first-search, wavefront

I'm trying to implement a wavefront algorithm and I have a problem with the function, that produces the map with specific gradients.

I've tried several different versions of the code below and none of them worked.

The starting point for the algorithm (the goal) is set to 1 before and from that point on each neighbour's gradient should be increased (similar to every wavefront algorithm), if the gradient hasn't bin altered yet.

`originX` and `originY` is the goal, from which the alorithm should start. `mapMatrix` is a global variable

`mapMatrix` looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 N 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 N 0 0 N 0 N
N N 0 0 N 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

(0 for rails, N(nil) for obstacles)

expected output example:

```
7 6 5 4 3 4 5
6 5 N 3 2 3 4
5 4 3 2 1 2 3
6 5 4 3 2 3 3
7 N 5 4 N 4 N
N N 6 5 N 5 6 
9 8 7 6 7 6 7
```

And with this code for example:

```
function pathFinder(originX, originY)
    northDir = originY - 1
    eastDir = originX + 1
    southDir = originY + 1
    westDir = originX - 1

    if northDir > 0 and mapMatrix[originX][northDir] == 0 then 
        mapMatrix[originX][northDir] = mapMatrix[originX][originY] + 1
        pathFinder(originX, northDir)

    end
    if eastDir <= 7 and mapMatrix[eastDir][originY] == 0 then 
        mapMatrix[eastDir][originY] = mapMatrix[originX][originY] + 1
        pathFinder(eastDir, originY)

    end
    if southDir <= 7 and mapMatrix[originX][southDir] == 0 then 
        mapMatrix[originX][southDir] = mapMatrix[originX][originY] + 1
        pathFinder(originX, southDir)

    end
    if westDir > 0 and mapMatrix[westDir][originY] == 0 then 
        mapMatrix[westDir][originY] = mapMatrix[originX][originY] + 1
        pathFinder(westDir, originY)
    end
end
```

I get this `mapMatrix`:

```
0 0 0 0 3 4 5
0 0 N 0 2 10 6
0 0 0 0 1 9 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 8
0 N 0 0 N 0 N
N N 0 0 N 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And if I switch the if statements arround it produces different version of `mapMatrix`

After making `northDir`, etc `local` the output looks like this: **EDIT**

```
33 24 23 22 3 4 5
32 25 N 21 2 11 6
31 26 27 20 1 10 7
30 29 28 19 20 9 8
31 N 29 18 N 10 N
N N 30 17 N 11 12
33 32 31 16 15 14 13
```

If more code or information is needed, I'd be happy to help

Comment: so mapMatrix is a table `{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,nil,0,0,0,0}, ....}` or what?  what is the expected output for a certain origin touple and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Piglet yes it is a table.

Comment: Make your variables `northDir,...` local.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I added the result above

Comment: why do you have two different codes for this? the first code causes a stack overflow for trivial example pathFinder(1,1)

Comment: @Piglet i tried arround a lot with different version in the hope that one would work

Comment: still missing your definition of mapMatrix

Comment: The line `mapMatrix[westDir][northDir] = ` is incorrect.  Only one dimension per time should be changed.

Comment: @Piglet the matrix is exactly as you described it in the first comment. answered that already i thought

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff changed it and changed the result above

Comment: You're currently implementing DFS.  You must use BFS instead.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff oh uhm, any suggestions? My plan was to implement BFS all along 0.o

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy - Keep following your plan and implement BFS (maybe you should re-read a description of what BFS is).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I've tried since I read some explanations of BFS and tried to implement it but somehow I enden up implementing DFS without even knowing it :/ If you could just tell me what part too look at specifically or something like that

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy - The whole idea of your program is wrong.  Delete your old code and write new one from scratch.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff oh fk me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just wrong at all. As `pathFinder` is called recursively in the first check, it will be just going in that direction until any obstacle appears, and than going in the next direction, and so on.

---

BFS is actually a pretty simple algorithm. It can be easily implemented iteratively on a queue without any recursion as follow:

1. Put initial node to a queue;
2. Pop first node from the queue and process it;
3. Push unprocessed adjacent nodes to the end of the queue;
4. If queue is not empty, go to the step 2.

In Lua on a rectangular matrix it can be implemented in about two or three dozen of lines:

```lua
function gradient(matrix, originX, originY)
    -- Create queue and put origin position and initial value to it.
    local queue = { { originX, originY, 1 } }

    repeat
        -- Pop first position and value from the queue.
        local x, y, value = unpack(table.remove(queue, 1))

        -- Mark this position in the matrix.
        matrix[y][x] = value

        -- Check position to the top.
        if y > 1 and matrix[y - 1][x] == 0 then
            -- If it is not already processed, push it to the queue.
            table.insert(queue, { x, y - 1, value + 1 })
        end

        -- Check position on the left.
        if x > 1 and matrix[y][x - 1] == 0 then
            table.insert(queue, { x - 1, y, value + 1 })
        end

        -- Check position to the bottom.
        if y < #matrix and matrix[y + 1][x] == 0 then
            table.insert(queue, { x, y + 1, value + 1 })
        end

        -- Check position on the right.
        if x < #matrix[y] and matrix[y][x + 1] == 0 then
            table.insert(queue, { x + 1, y, value + 1 })
        end

    -- Repeat, until queue is not empty.
    until #queue == 0
end

-- Just helper function to print a matrix.
function printMatrix(matrix)
    for _, row in pairs(matrix) do
        for _, value in pairs(row) do
            io.write(string.format("%2s", value))
        end
        io.write('\n')
    end
end

local mapMatrix = {
    {   0,   0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0, },
    {   0,   0, 'N', 0,   0, 0,   0, },
    {   0,   0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0, },
    {   0,   0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0, },
    {   0, 'N',   0, 0, 'N', 0, 'N', },
    { 'N', 'N',   0, 0, 'N', 0,   0, },
    {   0,   0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0, },
}

gradient(mapMatrix, 5, 3)
printMatrix(mapMatrix)

--[[
Produces:
 7 6 5 4 3 4 5
 6 5 N 3 2 3 4
 5 4 3 2 1 2 3
 6 5 4 3 2 3 4
 7 N 5 4 N 4 N
 N N 6 5 N 5 6
 9 8 7 6 7 6 7
]]
```

This is a complete script, runnable in the console.

---

But although, for illustrative purposes, this code is very simple, it is not very efficient. Each removal of the first item from the queue causes reindexing of the remaining items. For production code you should implement a linked list or something similar for the queue.

Comment: oh wow. thank you so so much. you've really helped me out a lot. and it's not ment for production. I'm just starting to learn lua ;)

Comment: I had to switch all uses of for e.g `matrix[y][x-1]` to `matrix[x -1][y] because the map I have to use has different X- and Y-origin settings, but besides that it worked perfectly